# Bashscript making a variable equal a command. error command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, md5sum

Hi i keep getting the error

```
./imagehash.sh: line 2: =: command not found
```

When i know that i set the `$CMD` variable correctly (i tried the command outside the bash script and it worked just fine)

here's my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
 $CMD='md5sum ../Desktop/cases/CourseworkCase/Evidence/image.dd'
 echo $CMD
```

UPDATE

fixed the bash so theres no spaces in the `$CMD` variable and put `''` around it but now i'm getting the error file `no such file or directory` i looked at the path and copied it letter for letter and its correct.

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Working example

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD="$(md5sum ../Desktop/cases/CourseworkCase/Evidence/image.dd)"
echo $CMD
```

## Explanation

1. To assign a variable **never put a `$` sign before** nor spaces around the equal sign. The variable assignment in bash is like this:

   ```
   MYVAR="CONTENT"
   ```
2. To create a variable with the output of a command you may use `$(command)`. This will execute `command` and return its output.
3. The output of `md5sum` will be like this:

   ```
   f110abe5b3cfd324c2e5128eb4733879 image.dd
   ```

   If do you want to isolate the md5 sum of the file name, you can use one of these lines instead:

   ```
   CMD="$(md5sum ../Desktop/cases/CourseworkCase/Evidence/image.dd | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
   CMD=($(md5sum ../Desktop/cases/CourseworkCase/Evidence/image.dd))
   ```

Comment: also please do not forget to quote $CMD. You can use this tool to check your script: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @helio: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086